# KendoPanelBar PreventDefault

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm having problems understanding how preventDefault function works.
I created a simple jsfiddle, but still, selections and expansion works and not prevented.

http://jsfiddle.net/XRfKb/15/

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:
How to prevent selection if page is not valid? Here's a piece of code:

```
panelBar.bind("select", function (e) {
   //some code here
   if (!isValid) {
            e.preventDefault(e); //doesn't work
            //this.select('#firstStep'); //doesn't work
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried your code in a standalone visual studio solution and it worked fine, preventDefault prevented the panel from expanding. One thing I noticed is that the kendo.web.min.js included in the fiddle is of an older release. I tested with Kendo UI Web v2012.1.515.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by using simple "click" events for links in the PanelBar instead of "select" events for PanelBar.

e.preventDefault and e.stopPropagation work fine for them.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you're using an old release from the last year. I've updated your jsFiddle accordingly:
http://jsfiddle.net/XRfKb/18/

Currently the select event can't be prevented. As of next release the select event can prevent link navigation, but not the actual selection of the item. We may consider preventing selection too.

Comment: Ok, but how can I prevent selecting of PanelBar? Imagine I use it to move to next view after validation. Currently when I click next item in PanelBar it gets selected and if the page was not valid then the view remains the same but selected item in PanelBar is wrong. I tried to bind to "select" event and call e.preventDefault under some conditions (thats not working as you say). I also tried call PanelBar select method again under the same conditions to go back to previous item, but that does not work as well. Can you suggest something? I've updated master post.